# Add always each value before each entry in object in numpy. insert

Tags: python, numpy

I have an 1D array a and everytime I have in  this array a zero value I would like to copy a complete array before this entry, for example :

```
b=np.ones(30)
```

I got the location of the needed entries with :

```
c=np.nonzero(a==0)
```

In doing so  :

```
len(c) > len(b)
```

If I then use :

```
np.insert(arr, obj, values, axis=None)
```

respectively

```
np.insert(a,c,b)
```

Np insert will always only copy one value of b before the position specified in c

**Question**

How do I have to modifiy the np. insert code that he will always copy all entries in values before ech entry in obj ?

Comment: Can you perhaps include an example of `a` and show the output of your code and what you would like to see?

Comment: For example a=[0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,3];  c=[0,1,3,6]; b= [10,11,12];  output  is [10  0 11  0  1 12  0  1  2 10  0  1  2  3]

Comment: The desired output would be [10 11 12 0 10 11 12 0 1 10 11 12 0 1 2 10 11 12]

Comment: Edit you question, adding the examples; formating is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list approach:

```
In [197]: a=[0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,3]
In [198]: for i in c[::-1]:
     ...:     a[i:i+1]=b+[a[i]]
     ...:     
In [199]: a
Out[199]: [10, 11, 12, 0, 10, 11, 12, 0, 1, 10, 11, 12, 0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

`insert` can insert single values at each `before`:

```
In [200]: arr
Out[200]: array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3])
In [201]: np.insert(arr, c, np.arange(10,15))
Out[201]: array([10,  0, 11,  0,  1, 12,  0,  1,  2, 13,  0,  1,  2,  3])
```

`insert` is written in Python, but is a bit complex, especially since it can handle multidimensional inserts (axis).  But essentially it does:

```
res = np.empty(result_size)
idx1 = <where original a values go>
# e.g. [ 3,  7,  8, 12, 13, 14, 18, 19, 20, 21]
res[idx1] = a
idx2 = <where insert values go>
# e.g. [0,1,2, 4,5,6, 9,10,11, 15,16,17]
res[idx2] = values
```

`idx1` can be derived from `idx2` with

```
mask=np.ones(res.shape, bool)
mask[idx2]=False
idx1 = np.where(mask)
```

So you only have to construct one or the other, which ever is easier.

Expanding that logic to your case could be get messy.  I suspect `@Divakar` can quickly come up with something using `cumsum` or `np.max.accumulate`.

A different iterative approach - add values of `b` one by one

```
In [234]: arr1 = arr.copy()
In [236]: for i in b:
     ...:     idx = np.where(arr1==0)[0]
     ...:     print(idx)
     ...:     arr1 = np.insert(arr1, idx, i)
     ...:     
[0 1 3 6]
[ 1  3  6 10]
[ 2  5  9 14]
In [237]: arr1
Out[237]: 
array([10, 11, 12,  0, 10, 11, 12,  0,  1, 10, 11, 12,  0,  1,  2, 10, 11,  12,  0,  1,  2,  3])
```

Given the overhead of creating arrays (and I'm sure `insert` has array overhead), I suspect this will be slower than the pure list iteration - unless the length of `c` (the insert points) is much larger than the length of `b`.  This also depends on being able to identify the original insert points at each iteration (here with `arr1==0`).

Comment: Thank you verry much for your help

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to duplicate the object array as often as len(value) using  np.tile(object, len(value)) and resort the values afterwards using np.sort(). The new array should then be used instead  of the inial object array in the np.insert function